# writing code for exception TypeError in python

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, typeerror, python-decorators

I have a function which looks like this:

```py
def fun(a,b,c=None):
    pass
```

When I call this function as `fun(1)` in python 3, It gives me error as `TypeError: fun() missing 1 required positional argument: 'b'` which is understandable but when I call this function in python 2, It gives me error as `TypeError: fun() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)`.

So I want to catch this error in python 2 as it is being caught in python 3 without switching to python 3. How I can achieve this? Also, If I am writing a decorator for this I need to preserve the signature of function outside the decorator.

Comment: the types of the errors aren't different, it's the message that differs. The default messages are defined in `C` and not possible to alter through Python directly. You could catch the exception in Python 2 and re-raise it with a similar exception message in Python 3 (but that requires a decent amount of introspecting the call stack and the function object to find the missing arg in the call).

Comment: I am new to python. Can you suggest me something to do this? @JimFasarakis-Hilliard

Comment: Honestly? Just don't use Python 2 is the best advice. Since this decision might not be yours to decide, though, you can always look at the `inspect` module in the stdlib which provides introspection capabilities that should help with what you're after.

Comment: Thank you. I will look into it

Answer (score 2):

What are you trying to achieve? python2 and python3 both throw 'TypeError', which means the caller is misusing the function 'fun'

```
def foo(a, b, c = None):
    pass

try:
    foo(1)
except TypeError:
    print("TypeError")
```

Calling it for python2:

```
python2 code_for_exception_type_error.py
TypeError
```

And python3:

```
python3 code_for_exception_type_error.py
TypeError
```

Comment: I am using python2. In my module I have a function like above. Now when somebody else will use this function(fun written in question above) of my module with incorrect parameters, I want to catch that thing and write a message which shows which positional argument was missing. Python3 handles this thing internally but not python 2. So how can I do this thing in python2 and throw my customized error with message. I hope I am clear now.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting this error is because you are not passing a value for the parameter 'b'. If you want to not pass a value for 'b', do the following:

```
def fun(a, b = None, c = None):
    pass

fun(1)
```

If you want to pass a value for the parameter b, do the following:

```
def fun(a, b, c = None):
    pass

bValue = None # whatever you want to pass for b
fun(1, bValue)
```